# compare first column in two files and print the first column same which is in first file

Tags: linux, awk

file1.txt

```
YGR192C
YLR044C
YLR110C
YKL152C
YOR382W
```

file2.txt

```
YLR044C PDC1
YGR192C TDH3
YLR110C CCW12
YKL152C GPM1
YOR382W FIT2
```

expected output: same column 1 order as in file1.txt with match value of column 2 from file2.txt

```
YGR192C TDH3
YLR044C PDC1
YLR110C CCW12
YKL152C GPM1
YOR382W FIT2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: You could also use search functionality of SO, where you could look for these kind of questions too here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]; next}  # read each element of file2 first col
     $1 in seen               # if there, print
' file2 file1
```

Since the expected output *changed*, you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$0; next}  # read each line of file2 indexed by first col
     $1 in seen { print seen[$1] }              # if there, print the line
' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next} ($1 in a) {print $1}' file2.txt file1.txt
YGR192C
YLR044C
YLR110C
YKL152C
YOR382W
```

without awk -

```
grep -f <(cut -d" " -f1 file2.txt) file1.txt
YGR192C
YLR044C
YLR110C
YKL152C
YOR382W
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$0; next} $1 in map{print map[$1]}' file2 file1
YGR192C TDH3
YLR044C PDC1
YLR110C CCW12
YKL152C GPM1
YOR382W FIT2
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ed Mortan....script works perfectly for me.

Comment: I don't know what that means. The answer I posted solves the problem you asked about so you should accept that answer and ask a new question if you have one.